# How to Log from Async Thread in MSBuild Task

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a MSBuild target that starts a process and returns. I now want to somehow show a notification when the process is finished.

My first attempt was to use `Log.LogMessage` for all output of the task. This does not show any output. My guess is that the process object gets disposed before anything is read (but the process itself runs to completion).

```cs
<UsingTask TaskName="ExecAsync" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
        <ParameterGroup>
            <!--The file path is the full path to the executable file to run-->
            <FilePath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <!--The arguments should contain all the command line arguments that need to be sent to the application-->
            <Arguments ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />

            <WorkingDirectory ParameterType="System.String" Required="true"/>
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, Arguments);
                processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
                processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data))
                    {
                        Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, args.Data);
                    }
                };
                p.Start();
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>
```

My second attempt was to use throw the whole code into a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, wait for the process and use `Log.LogMessage` after it is finished. This also does not write anything to the output.

```cs
<UsingTask TaskName="ExecAsync" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
        <ParameterGroup>
            <!--The file path is the full path to the executable file to run-->
            <FilePath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
            <!--The arguments should contain all the command line arguments that need to be sent to the application-->
            <Arguments ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />

            <WorkingDirectory ParameterType="System.String" Required="true"/>
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, Arguments);
                    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
                    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Finished");
                });
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>
```

Is there any good way to achieve a notification when this process completes?

Comment: Targets are executed sequentially, so I think it's ok to perform blocking wait

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 'first attempt', I think you are generally right about why that is failing. But a nuance is that the MSBuild Task is probably also disposed before the process completes.

Regarding your 'second attempt', the wait is within the function passed to Run(). The MSBuild Task is probably still disposed before the process is complete.

Your inline task definition becomes the body of an [Task.Execute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.task.execute?view=msbuild-17-netcore). Effectively your code is:

```cs
            public bool Execute()
            {
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, Arguments);
                    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
                    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Finished");
                });

                return !Log.HasLoggedErrors;
            }
```

`Run()` starts a thread and then `Execute()` returns without waiting. I think the code passed to `Run()` should be your `Execute()` and the call of `Run()` should be removed.

e.g. something like:

```xml
        <Task>
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, Arguments);
                processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
                processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Finished");
            </Code>
        </Task>
```

I suspect, given the task name of `ExecAsync`, that you are attempting to have a long running process run in parallel with the rest of your project. If that is the case, the code above defeats that purpose. Further, an MSBuild task is just not capable of what you want.

Instead use an [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022) with `BuildInParallel="true"`, e.g.

```xml
        <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)" BuildInParallel="true" Targets="MyLongRunningProcess"/>
```

In the `MyLongRunningProcess` target, the standard `Exec` task can be used.

Comment: Wouldn't the MSBuild task still block the build until its task is finished? As the `BuildInParallel` Property only applies to what it does itself, which will only be a single target for a single project, so nothing can be done in parallel.

What i would want to achieve is to start a process to just do its thing and continue with the build as normal, but at the very end, before saying "Build succeeded", wait for all these processes to finish, so the build really is "finished".

Comment: What you want to do as you described, "... start a process ... and continue with the build as normal, but at the very end ... wait for all these processes to finish ...", MSBuild doesn't support. MSBuild doesn't have a 'wait' or an 'event sink' for arbitrary processes.

Comment: The `Exec` task within the `MyLongRunningProcess` target will block, but the target will be running in a parallel project. The `MSBuild` task will not block because of the `BuildInParallel="true"` attribute. The `MSBuild` task will run within the same msbuild process but will have its own 'project' loaded. It doesn't matter if the project is loaded from the same file on disk or from a different file.